# A symbol to denote the set of prime numbers ?

Tags: notation, convention, soft-question

It strikes me that there is no widely accepted symbol to denote the set of usual prime numbers in $\mathbb{N}$.

Look:

$$\zeta(s)=\prod_{p\in \mathrm{?}}\frac{1}{(1-p^{-s})}$$

Wouldn't it be nicer to have a standard symbol to put in place of the "$\mathrm{?}$" instead of writing just $\Pi_p$ and specifying by words "where $p$ ranges in the set of prime numbers"?

> Is there a reason for this lack of standard notation? Perhaps because primes do not form a sufficiently nice algebraic structure?

---

> Have you seen expressive instances in the literature to define such a symbol?

Comment: $|\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})|$.

Comment: @Moosbrugger: If $|{\rm Spec}(\mathbb{Z}|$ means the set of points of the scheme ${\rm Spec}(\mathbb{Z}$, that's not so good, since ${\rm Spec}(\mathbb{Z}$ also contains the point $(0)$. OTOH, if your notation is supposed to mean the closed points, I think it's sufficiently nonstandard to confuse people.

Comment: I think that $|X|$ is fairly standard notation for the set of closed points of a scheme $X$. E.g., Deligne uses it in Weil I and II.

Comment: I think based on the general wisdom "$n$ is a number", "$p$ is a prime number" in number theory.

Comment: @Joe: $\operatorname{Maxspec}\mathbb Z$ :)

Comment: @GHfromMO as long as you don't need several primes in one formula. Then a symbol for a set you're drawing them from would be a nice thing to have.

Answer (score 38):

I just write $\displaystyle \prod_{p \text{ prime}}$.

Comment: Leaves the question: 'prime' in which structure? :)
[Sorry could not resist.]

Comment: @quid: well, presumably there are words before and after this and it should be clear from context. As a mild extension if I am talking about a fixed ring $R$ I think I could safely write "P a prime ideal" instead. 

Comment: I did not mean it that seriously, which I even tried to signal. In case you dislike the comment, I'll delete it (and then this one too of course).   
  

Comment: ....and sometimes it is more convenient to write $\sum_{\text{even }n\ge 0} s_n$ than $\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_{2n}$.

Comment: @quid & @Qiaochu: Maybe there are times when you want to say $\prod_{p\text{ prime}} s_p =\text{something that depends on which structure it is}$.  (But maybe I'm also taking this more seriously than I could have......)

Comment: @Michael: then I might write $\displaystyle \prod_{p \text{ prime in Foo}}$. I am not averse to writing long conditions in my sums... 

Comment: @Michael, my point was only that the suggested notation is not a true substitute for having a notation for the set of prime numbers. This is perhaps a bit pedantic. In general, both the originally suggested notation as well as all kinds of other things can be useful. Typically , I do not use 'voluminous' sub- and superscripts but this is I would say to a large extent a matter of personal taste.    

Answer (score 29):

I've read $\mathbb{P}$ many times and also use it.

Comment: I've seen that one too.  I've also seen $P$ and $\mathcal{P}$.  I think I've even seen $\Pi$, but I don't like that one.

Comment: `$\prod_{p \in \Pi} f(p)$` is revolting.

Comment: I think it is reasonable to reserve the \mathbb script for algebraic structures (rings, fields, and alike). Perhaps, $\mathcal P$ would be the best choice - but I don't really believe MO being influencial enough to set up a notation like this, whatever we decide here.

Comment: @Seva: $\mathbb{A}^n$?

Comment: @Seva: you only have to elect me Emperor of Notation...

Comment: I would like $\mathbb{P}$ although I reserve it for probabilities. OF course there would be no conflict but I like my notation to not have homonyms, even if they can be disambiguated by context.

Comment: @Seva: In complex analysis $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the open unit disk and $\mathbb{H}$ the open upper half plane. The latter notation is also used in number theory (modular forms). I think that $\mathbb{P}$ is quite reasonable, because it is very unlikely to be confused with 
$\mathbb{P}^n$ (projective space) from algebraic geometry.

Comment: @Michael: Isn't P more common for probabilities than $\mathbb{P}$? 
I have only a couple of books about probability; both use P.

Comment: @Marius: I prefer $\mathbb{H}$ for quaternions and $\mathfrak{H}^n$ for hyperbolic $n$-space!

Comment: $\mathbb{P}$ fits right in with $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},\ldots$

Comment: $\mathbb P$ is used for the set of irrationals by many topologists

Comment: @DouglasSirk I guess the P stands for the p in "irrational"? :D

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, you made my day, thanks!  (Quote: P stands for the p in "irrational")

Answer (score 23):

To answer the actual question, I don't know any standard symbol; I've seen $P$, $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathtt{PRIMES}$. (The last seems more common in the CS-literature, such as [this](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf) famous paper.)

I would like to use this as an opportunity to make my standard plea for using multi-letter symbols; and to argue in this case for $\mathtt{PRIMES}$. There are more important concepts than can be represented by upper and lower case letters, even allowing multiple fonts and Greek letters. Moreover, multi-letter symbols are far more self-explanatory than single character ones; I can open up a paper, see $\mathtt{PRIMES}$ in the middle of a page and have a very good guess what it represents; not so with $\mathbb{P}$.

Moreover, if you tie down the simple one letter symbols for major objects, you'll won't have them available for little dummy roles like the $p$ and $s$ in your formula. For example, suppose you needed the partial product 
$$\prod_{\substack{ p \in \mathtt{PRIMES}\\ p < P }} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$
and needed to work with expressions like $O(\min(P^{-1} \log P, 10))$ for how things depended on your bound. (Open up pretty much any analytic number theory paper to see examples like this.) Wouldn't you be glad you hadn't wasted $P$ on a set, which is unlikely to appear in any complicated algebraic manipulations?

PS: Of course, in many cases, spelling things out in words is the best solution. There is certainly nothing wrong with "$\prod_p \ \left( \textrm{such-and-such} \right)$, where $p$ runs through the primes".

Comment: This sounds reasonable. For the same reason, we should probably write for instance (Groups) for the category of groups instead of (Grp) or even more confusing abbreviations such as (Gp) or (Gps) (which I have all seen so far). But maybe it is a bit redundant to write such a long technical formula $p \in \mathtt{PRIMES}$ if you are not really interested in this *set* of all prime numbers and manipulate it by set-theoretic means. In the case of a simple product which runs over the primes, then I would prefer the notation proposed by Qiaochu (which is, of course, very popular).

Comment: Yeah, agreed. I'd have to think a little to come up with an example where using a notation for the set of primes itself was the best option. 

Comment: although I find the argument to avoid "font / symbol overload" of the letter 'p' fairly compelling, I also wonder why a concept of such high importance does not yet have its own symbol. I guess, once more number theory is taught at grade-school level.....

Comment: @David: $\mathtt{PRIMES}\setminus\{2,3\}$ could be an instance.

Comment: What about $\mathtt{PRM}$ (to not waste too much space...) ?

Comment: unknowngoogle, what about the variants based on just P to waste even less space? ;) More seriously, while at least in theory I have some sympathy for the idea of writing-things-out, it is excessively hard for me to imagine that a half-way solution like PRM will be useful, in the spirit of the answer 'opening up a paper in the middle.' Quick question: Who will see PRM written somewhere in the middle of a paper and default to thinking this is the set of prime numbers, and who it is something defined earlier in the paper? (Except context is *so* clear that nothing is required, cf GH.)   

Comment: And, before someone reminds me of Hom, Ker, Ext, Tor, sin, or whatnot, let me add that these are already standards, are typically primted in standard font, and are in some (vague) sense notations of a different form.

Comment: Mostly I don't like this.  I guess use $\mathtt{PRIMES}$ only if you also use $\mathtt{INTEGERS}$, $\mathtt{RATIONALS}$, and $\mathtt{REALS}$ .  That is, in a computer program.

Comment: I still want to use $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but if you're willing to write $p \in \texttt{PRIMES}$ then why not just $p: \text{prime}$ as in 
Qiaochu Yuan's answer? That's as clear yet shorter (and I personally find it a bit less ugly).

Comment: $\mathbb P$ is used for the set of irrationals by many topologists

Comment: There would be no problems with single-letter symbols, nor with agreeing upon their meaning, if only math had some syntax for DECLARATIONS, as in programming languages. Then you could introduce whatever symbol you like by declaring its name and type, and from then on, you could use that symbol (even a one-letter one) in the rest of the formulas. Isn't that what Alonzo Church tried to accomplish with his Lambda Calculus? (To get rid of "undefined symbols" from mathematical symbolic notation.)

Answer (score 15):

As in other answers and comments: *context* usually suffices to explain that $p$ is a prime, whether in the rational integers or whatever. That is, when possible, no notation at all is clearer (and less bulky and visually noisy) than any possible notation.

Similarly, as I was slow to learn, objects' notations need not make explicit reference to every parameter upon which they depend: context should make most of it clear, and, if context is failing to do so, then it may be as much a complaint about the author's setting of context as anything else.

Also, as in other comments and answers, committing succinct single-letter labels for global variables is often wasteful.

Also, as computer programming teaches us, the fewer global variables the better, and, if one *has* such, their names should be self-explanatory, not cryptic, regardless of the illusion of "saving".

Even in situations where clarification is essential, in-lined expressions can be almost entirely prose, rather than symbolic, and displayed expressions can have a small verbal comment, as in 
$$
\zeta(s)\;=\;\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}\hskip30pt\hbox{(product over primes $p$)}
$$

Comment: At the risk of becoming 'the noise' on this question with my comments regarding 'prime': the prime elements of the rational integers are *not* the prime numbers. 

Comment: (Sometimes "noise" raises questions that need answering, because they're pervasive, even if one might argue that they "oughtn't be asked", for stylistic reason.)

About "prime element" versus "primes", for example: first, saying "primes", esp. in $\mathbb Z$, by universal convention does denote the positive thingies we expect; second, context should clarify. In larger rings of integers, "primes" often comes to denote "prime ideals", so the issue changes. Or, because one _needs_ to clarify, "prime elements mod units". And so on.

Really, _context_ should clarify, not some brittle convention.

Comment: First, in view of your parenthetical comment, let me say explictly that I certainly did not want to suggest that you were unaware of the difference. Sorry, in case it should have looked liked this. 
Second, I did not comment on what you responded to, but the first line. For me the by far most natural interp. of  'p is a prime, whether in the rational integers or whatever' is that p is supposed to be a prime element of the rat. integers (or whatever other structure); as 'a prime' needs to make sense in 'whatever' too. So, this seemed a bit confusing to me in a discussion on the prime numbers.

Answer (score 8):

For a scheme $X$, people sometimes use $\lvert X\rvert$ to denote the set of closed points of $X$. So the set of primes is $|\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})|$ and you have:$$\zeta(s)=\prod_{p\in\lvert \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})\rvert}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}.$$

This formula of course generalizes to give the $\zeta$-function of any scheme $X$ of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$ (e.g., a variety of finite type over a finite field): $$\zeta_X(s)=\prod_{x\in\lvert X\rvert}\frac{1}{1-|\kappa(x)|^{-s}}$$
where $\kappa(x)$ is the residue field at $x$ and $\lvert\kappa(x)\rvert$ is its order.

Comment: Minor nitpicking: $\left\vert\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})\right\vert$ is the set of prime _ideals_ of $\mathbb{Z}$, not the set of the actual prime _numbers_.

Comment: Also remark that usually $|X|$ denotes the underlying topological space of a scheme, whereas for *varieties*, where the closed points are dense, it is often meant to be the set of closed points (for example in Deligne's work on the Weil conjectures).

Answer (score 5):

Since I commented so much, let me also try an answer.
I find this question somehow difficult, since 'standard' seems so vague to me.
[In some sense it is a very long comment, the main message is as in Martin Brandenburg's answer.]

If one asks for a true standard, then, no there is none. But, I think this is a bit much to ask for.

$\mathbb{N}$ is used in the question without explanation so a some sort of standard.

But, is it? Actually, to me there is less of a *standard* notation for the nonnegative and the positive integers than for the prime numbers (as cryptical expressed in a now deleted comment). Some people use $\mathbb{N}$ to mean the nonnegative integers others to denote the positve integers. (The respective other being denoted by $\mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ and $\mathbb{N}_0$ or something along these lines.)
So, basically, one has to define the notation if one wishes to be sure that there is no misunderstanding; or, one uses both nonnegative and positive sufficiently frequently, because each of the pairs then makes clear which is which. [And, indeed, I spent once considerable time to figure out whether in some paper now $\mathbb{N}$ included zero or not; as I needed the result specifically for $0$...at least it did.]

To wit, Henri Cohen in his recent two volume book on number theory refuses to use $\mathbb{N}$ for this reasons and uses appropriate 'decorations' of $\mathbb{Z}$ instead.

And, then there is also the question of $\mathbb{N}$ vs. $\mathbf{N}$ (and rarely, but I just saw it in the paper mentioned by David Speyer, $\mathcal{N}$). Even for the integers there is not a true standard, as the fonts vary in the same way; same for reals, complex, rationals (at least for bf vs bb).

So, why should there be a truer standard for the primes?

And if one ask for something essentially as standard as the above, then I would say yes there is: a capital P in some 'special font' blackboard bold, caligraphic, or boldface. Depending on ones choice regarding the font for, say, the integers with the exception of the concern raised by Seva or the mentioned 'notation-clashes', so that then caligraphic is not at all unusual.

---

Now, whether or not one should use such a symbol for the primes or not seems to me is a bit of an orthogonal discussion. I'd say it depends on the field, even on the specific paper, and the personal style. In some of my papers I do use it, in some not; depends if it seems useful.

It is true that one is much less likely to use the prime numbers as a 'building block' in some constrcut and thus needs a symbol, while say $\mathbb{Z}^n$, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and plenty of other things are used often.

But, then why $\mathbb{N}$ (assuming it does not contain $0$)? This could also be avoided
most of the time, or similar arguments could be made.

---

So, there is not a unique standard, but several standard notations (virtually all some variation on P, namely in blackboardbold, caligraphic, or boldface), which in those fields that need the notation are used frequently; to quote something recent, e.g., Iwaniec&Kowalski have $\mathbb{P}$ as a notation, just like $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},...$

Comment: Just a tangential comment: for me $\mathbf{N}$ is poor man's $\mathbb{N}$ !  ;)

Comment: Seriously; I think the notation $\mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathbf{N}$ for what it matters) really is *the* (most) *standard notation* for *non-negative* integers (I don't recall having seen it used to denote something different from $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$). For the positive integers I like the notation $\mathbb{N}^+$.

Comment: unknowngoogle, regarding non-neg. and positive, this might be true for you and your mathematical environment. But, it is certainly not universal!  
Again, I can point to Iwaniec&Kowalski (and they care a lot about exposition, coventions, choice of symbols); and could point to various other places. 
Regarding, the bf vs bb: and, Jean-Pierre Serre says (paraphrasing) blackboard bold is for blackboards and not for print; various people agree and adhere to this. Personally I actually like bb as you, but my N does not contain 0. And each of us, is by no means alone. 

Comment: Aesthetics for mathematical typesetting have changed and evolved much since the time of Serre.

Answer (score 1):

What about $\mathbb{N}\boldsymbol{'}$ for the set of prime numbers in the monoid $\mathbb{N}$? :)

And, of course $M\boldsymbol{'}$ for primes in a monoid $M$. It could even be shorthened to just $\boldsymbol{'}$ when it's understood that the monoid is $\mathbb{N}$.

Let's see:

$$\zeta(s)=\prod_{p\in \mathbb{N}\boldsymbol{'}}\frac{1}{(1-p^{-s})}$$

or even just

$$\zeta(s)=\prod_{\,p \;\,\boldsymbol{'}}\frac{1}{(1-p^{-s})}$$

or

$$\zeta(s)=\prod_{p \;:\,\boldsymbol{'}}\frac{1}{(1-p^{-s})}$$

Comment: I don't think $\Bbb N$ being a monoid is universally agreed upon.

Comment: @AliCaglayan: in which sense?

Comment: In the UK for example most mathematicians who aren't set theorists tend to take $/Bbb N$ as $/Bbb Z^+$.

Answer (score -1):

The set of prime numbers, though not having fixed or regular structure within it, should be symbolized as **N'** either in Boldface or Blackboard Bold type with the apostrophe or prime symbol to its right as a superscript denoting that set or subset of natural numbers (**N**) as being that of PRIME numbers.

Comment: should be symbolized?